# Windows 7 Enterprise Activation

Tags: windows-7, licensing, activation

I borrowed a Windows 7 Enterprise disk from work because it hasn't been released to the general public yet and installed it on a personal machine.  I got the machine all setup with my programs then I then realized I couldn't buy a license for it and the activation would expire after a month.  So now I'm stuck, I don't want to reinstall windows but I want to be legit.  Is it possible to activate Enterprise with an Ultimate key or downgrade Enterprise to Ultimate?

Thanks

Comment: This question belongs on Superuser.com

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know-no. Once your activation server is setup at work, you may be able to activate over the VPN back to your office.

Comment: If they are using KMS, it will periodically call home to the KMS server. Unless he's always VPN'd he'll run in to some problems.